# WPF: Best way to react to change in datagrid content?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a datagrid with two readonly DataGridTextColumns and one DataGridTemplateColumn with a TextBox in it. (The reason I went for a textbox rather than just a text column is because i wanted a context menu on each datagrid row with an option to rename which which turned out to be easiest with this approach).

```
        <DataGrid Grid.Row="0" Name="dgUsers" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Users, Mode=TwoWay}">
            <DataGrid.RowStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
                    <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource dataGridRowContextMenu}" />
                </Style>
            </DataGrid.RowStyle>
            <DataGrid.Columns>

                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}" IsReadOnly="True" />

                <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="Auto" Header="Middle Name">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBox Name="middleName" Text="{Binding MiddleName}" Style="{StaticResource DataGridTextBox}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>

                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Last Name" Binding="{Binding LastName}" IsReadOnly="True"/>


            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

The contents of the datagrid are twoway binded to a collection of objects in my view model. Each row corresponds to a User. Those Users objects in my viewmodel are hooked up to a database. I want to make things such that when a user changes the text in the editable column (the column where each row has a text box), the database is modified accordingly (after some data validation and such).

My question is: what is a good MVVM way of listening for a change in the template column and reacting to it?

I tried using the TextChanged event:

```
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="Auto" Header="Middle Name">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBox Name="middleName" Text="{Binding MiddleName}" Style="{StaticResource DataGridTextBox}"
                                     TextChanged="middleName_TextChanged"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

But then the middleName_TextChanged() method in my xaml.cs code behind gets called with every character added to the text box... ideally I want a method that only gets called when the focus leaves the text box (not with every character added).

I also considered launching the method to do input validation from the set method of the Property of User that this column is binded to (the set method of User.MiddleName) but this too is called with each character inserted into the text box.

Answer (score 0):

In your .xaml file add a `CollectionViewSource` like this

```
 <Window.Resources>
        <CollectionViewSource x:Key="ItemCollectionViewSource"  CollectionViewType="ListCollectionView"/>
 </Window.Resources>
```

And then in your `DataGrid` put the `DataContext` to `ItemCollectionViewSource` like this

```
DataContext="{StaticResource ItemCollectionViewSource}"
```

Now in code behind set your database to the `ItemCollectionViewSource` like this

```
CollectionViewSource itemCollectionViewSource;
itemCollectionViewSource = (CollectionViewSource)(FindResource("ItemCollectionViewSource"));
itemCollectionViewSource.Source = YourDataBase;
```

Now any changes in a twoway binding would reflect on the database.

Comment: this looks like an ideal solution. Thank you very much. However, there are a lot of steps and many layers to go through between the datagrid and actually updating the database. I dont want to bind the database directly to the grid.
What I am looking for, is I want to have a function in my view model which gets called when the content of a datagrid row gets changed (not after each character added but when the textbox loses focus and the text has been changed). This function should know for which row this change was made, and what the new content is.

Comment: I think by default `TextBox` only updates the your database when it loses focus and not when a character is changed. Therefore you could just use the method I mentioned.